# How to get coefficients with cross validation model

Tags: python, svm, cross-validation

How do I get coefficients with cross-validation model? When I do cross-validation I get scores for the CV model, how can I get coefficients?

```
#Split into training and testing
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(samples, scores, test_size = 0.30, train_size = 0.70)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
scores = cross_val_score(clf, x_train, y_train, cv=5)
scores
```

And I want to print the coefficient associated with each feature

```
   #Print co-efficients of features
    for i in range(0, nFeatures):
    print samples.columns[i],":", coef[0][i]
```

This one is without cross-validation, which provides coefficients

```
#Create SVM model using a linear kernel
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(x_train, y_train)
coef = model.coef_
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use [model_selection.cross_validate](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate) (with `return_estimator=True`) instead of cross_val_score. It's a lot more flexible so you can access the estimators used for each fold:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1)
cv_results = cross_validate(clf, x_train, y_train, cv=5, return_estimator=True)

for model in cv_results['estimator']:
    print(model.coef_)
```

should give you want you're looking for, hopefully! (You can access the metrics via `cv_results['train_score']` and `cv_results['test_score']`)

Comment: So, if I print (samples.columns[i],":", coef[0][i]), will I get the average coefficient from the cross validation model for each column? @fordy

Comment: Sure yes, if you want that you'll just need to load each `model.coef_` result into an ndarray or similar data structure and then calculate each coefficient's mean across the folds.